# How do I Nest If/Then statements

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to add a word, as well as a comma but only if the next field isn't empty.  If it is empty then I just want to add a word because it's the end of a list.  My problem is if the field is empty, it won't show my word and Product1.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't figure it out.  I had it as an Else but it kept showing the word and not the product1.

```
%%[ if not empty(@Product2) then ]%% 
  not empty 
%%= v(@Product1) =%%,
%%[ if empty(@Product2) then ]%% 
  empty 
%%= v(@Product1) =%%%%[ENDIF]%%%%[ENDIF]%%
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Once you have done so, could you please update your post title with a relevant title? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this in one line with an [**iif()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm) (inline-if) statement:

```
%%=v(@Product1)=%%%%=iif(not empty(@product2), concat(", ", @product2), "")=%%
```

Of without the `iif()`:

```
%%=v(@Product1)=%%
%%[

if not empty(@product2) then

  ouput(concat(", ", @product2))

endif

]%%
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Are there any examples on how to do the one line with iif()?

Comment: I used an `iif()` in my example.